# How can I sync the version of a windows application and the installer

Tags: version, updates, installshield, windows

I have a windows application where I am creating an installer for it with InstallShield. The installer will be posted in a login-secured location on the internet. When the program starts up, I am going to have it check the download site to see if it needs to be updated, and if so direct the user to the site to update the app.

The problem is the version numbers. The app knows its own version number, and I can create an API to put on the site that can read the version number of the installer, but how can I keep them in sync? I'd rather not have to do it manually every time there's a build.

The installer is required to be behind a login wall and it can't have any way to direct link to it, so the site will feed it to the user with a binary stream. I had been experimenting with ClickOnce, but I couldn't find a way for it to create a single-file installer and it doesn't allow for authorization when updating.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach depends on how you're building things. This answer assumes you are using a build system to come up with each version number, and specify it downstream to all the built items.

`IsCmdBld ... -z "ProductVersion=1.2.3.4"` can be used to specify the version at the command line. Be sure to consider that the (optional) fourth field of the ProductVersion is largely ignored by Windows Installer, and adjust your version numbering scheme as necessary.

Alternately the automation interface can be used to edit the project, and set the ProductVersion on the [ISWiProject object](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm). This is more flexible, but requires modifying the project before subsequently building it.